# sed: remove lines before A and after Z in file

Tags: bash, sed

Using sed, I'm trying to remove everything before a defined pattern and everything after a 
different one.

`head` and `tail` don't quite cut it because they just remove lines, not characters.

From:

```
0
0
0A
Z0
)
>
```

To:

```
A
Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
sed -ne '
    /A/,/Z/ {
        /A/ s/^[^A]*//;
        /Z/ s/\(Z\).*$/\1/;
        p;
    }
' infile
```

Assuming `infile` with content:

```
0
0
01234A56789
1
2
01234Z56789
)
>
```

Result will be:

```
A56789
1
2
01234Z
```